# Check if nested attributes changed after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I've been struggling with this for a bit now. What is the best way to check if you added, removed or changed some child objects.

For example:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_save :setup_task

  # =============== ASSOCIATIONS ===============
  has_many :lists, :through => :map_list_tasks

  def setup_task
    if list_attributes_changed?
      do something
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure how to go about this. I know how to check if an attribute on the local object changed. How can I do this on the children?

Thanks

EDIT

The problem with using a callback on the child is that the method I am running, pulls millions of records, does some math and comparisons, and then saves millions of new records. If I were to trigger this on save of the list, It would run 4 times instead of 1 (or however many lists got added to the task). Since it takes about 25 minutes to run, this is not ideal. It would take over an hour, and put uneccessary load on the box. The other problem is that the method really should be run from the "Task" because the options chosen for each of the lists added determine what is to happen on the list. For example, you can add 4 lists, and configure each of them to be 25 percent. In that case it will split the resources between all 4 evenly. So if I were to run this from the list, i would still need to grab the task, then all children of that task, then compare options saved and run the method

Comment: What do you mean by child objects? please explain.

Comment: Task has many lists. My task form has nested form for lists. When I add, remove, or edit those lists on the task form, I want to run the setup_task. If the attributes on the task itself changed (but not the list attributes) then I do NOT want to run setup_task

Comment: In this case you should have `def setup_task` callback in `List` model class. When a list object is saved then update the related task, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Surya, you'll be better working with the `list` model

---

**List Model**

You have to remember that `nested objects` are only a way to handle other models' data in a parent model. The actual data is handled by the respective model (in your case `list`)

I'd do this:

```
#app/models/list.rb
Class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_save :setup_task

    def setup_task
        do something 
    end
end
```

I'm not entirely sure of the context of your code, but I'll surmise you won't need to check if the associated collection has been updated, as `after_save` will suggest something's been saved?

If you let me know what you're trying to achieve with `setup_task`, I'll be able to create some code for your method!

Comment: I understand, normally I would have done this, but i've got some special cases here. I put an updated explanation. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I just did it:

```
class Parent
  def children_attributes=(attributes)
    hashes = attributes.is_a?(Hash) ? attributes.values : attributes
    @destroying_children = hashes.any? { _1.has_key?(:_destroy) }
    super
  end

  after_save do
    children_changed = @destroying_children || children.any?(&:saved_changes?)

    do_stuff if children_changed
  end
end
```